# zt for horizontal scrolling

Tags: scrolling

I love the keybindings `zt` `zb` and `zz`. They redraw the current window such that your cursor stays at the same place in the document, but it moves on your screen. The cursor will now be at the **t**op, the **b**ottom, or, well, ..., the **z**enter.

Does the same keybings exist for horizontal movement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `zs` and `ze` may be helpful. Try `help: zs` `help ze`.

```
                                                    zs
```

> `zs`                      Scroll the text horizontally to position the cursor
>                           at the start (left side) of the screen.  This only
>                           works when 'wrap' is off.  {not in Vi}

```
                                                    ze
```

> `ze`                      Scroll the text horizontally to position the cursor
>                           at the end (right side) of the screen.  This only
>                           works when 'wrap' is off.  {not in Vi}

Additionally, these two commands let the cursor still stay at the original place in the text.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Interestingly, I searched before under `:help z`, but then looked for the keyword `redraw`, which can be found for `zt`, `zb` and `zz`, but not for `ze` and `zs`. That's

Comment: Analog to `scrolloff` (offset for vertical scrolling), there is also an offset for horizontal scrolling. E.g.: `:set sidescrolloff=8`.